# indent being odd -- fix or choose an alternative

Tags: c, coding-style, indentation, gnu-indent

I'm running `indent` with arguments `-npro -kr -i8 -ts8 -sob -l80 -ss -ncs -cp1`, all is good except two obstacles:

1) It tends to put an extra space after `*` in statements like `mytype_t * my;`, i.e.

```
void my_function(my_type *ptr)
```

turns into

```
void my_function(my_type * ptr)
```

2) It places extra space after `&` symbol in expressions like `(uint16_t *) & q->drops` i.e.

```
stats->drops = (uint16_t *) &q->drops
```

turns into

```
stats->drops = (uint16_t *) & q->drops
```

Running `indent` with `-nss` or without `-ss` does not solve the problem.

Is there a way to tell `indent` not to do this? If not, what are the alternatives to `indent` ?

Thanks.

**SOLUTION**

```
% indent -T my_type -T uint16_t
```

Comment: I don't understand the second case. Is something missing there?

Comment: Sidenote: 8 chars indentation is not a good idea. typical values are 2 to 4 spaces (4 most common). 8 spaces will make the code actually less readable.

Comment: `(uint16_t *) &->drops` is no valid syntax anyway.

Comment: Can you show an example (a short one) of a valid C source with these statements before and after `indent`?

Comment: @Eugene Sh., I updated the original post.

Comment: Have you tried other options such as eliminating the `-ss` argument or using `-nss` What happens when you do it with no arguments so that it is completely with the default?

Comment: @sabbahillel, it doesn't help unfortunately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [`man indent`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/indent):

> You must use the `'-T'` option to tell indent the name of all the
>   typenames in your program that are defined by typedef. `'-T'` can be
>   specified more than once, and all names specified are used. For
>   example, if your program contains
>
> `typedef unsigned long CODE_ADDR;`
>      `typedef enum {red, blue, green} COLOR;`
>
> you would use the options `-T CODE_ADDR -T COLOR`.

So it seems like `indent` doesn't know about the `stdint.h` types, so you have to let it know you are using them by passing `-T uint16_t -T mytype_t`

Comment: thank you, it seems to solve the first problem (my_type * ptr), but not the second (extra space after &).

Comment: Looks like it is considering `&` to be a bitwise AND. I wonder how can we convince it it is not... Have you actually did `-T uint16_t` to let it know it is a type cast?

Comment: oh it actually works, I mistakenly passed "-T uint32_t" instead. Thank you.

Comment: Good. Then it's not a bug.

Answer (score 2):

After some searching, I couldn't find the option to remove the space between type and pointer. What was weird is it only happens when that type ends with a `_t`. So, this probably does not answer your question. However a good alternative to `indent` is `astyle`. For the style you're looking for, you can use these flags:

```
astyle --style=kr --indent=tab
```

I really hope this helps.